# How to assign value to a two-dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

I have a two-dimensional array generated like this:

```
two_dimensional = Array.new(3){Array.new(5, 0)}
```

which after `two_dimensional.each {|a| p a}`  generates this :

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

I have coordinates coming like this (x,y). How can I assign (x,y) to two_dimensional ?

if I do  `two_dimensional[2][0] = 1`  for the point: (2,0) I expect this:

```
[0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

but what gets generated is:

```
[0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0,0]
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: As per your expectation you should write it as `two_dimensional[0][2] = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a 3x3 array

```
a = [0,1,3]
    [4,5,6]
    [7,8,9]
```

that would mean

```
a = [[0,1,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

so if you want `a[1][2]`

```
a[1] = [4,5,6]
```

so

```
a[1][2] = 6
```

Recall that indexing begins at zero.

An easy way to remember is that a one-dimensional array is expressed as a row, not a column.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the row and column reversed.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular problem, you can replace the positions of `x` and `y` such as:

```
two_dimensional[0][2] = 1
```

but that would not be a good solution for a system with a wider perspective. You are mixing up two systems: one in which an array consists of rows and another in which an array consists of columns.

You have to decide one, don't mix. Just stick to one system. If you think you would want to access the way you suggest, then have the array transposed from the beginning. Instead of:

```
two_dimensional = Array.new(3){Array.new(5, 0)}
```

do:

```
two_dimensional = Array.new(5){Array.new(3, 0)}
```

and whenever you want to display it, you can use the `transpose` method.